# Visual studio web deploy errror ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

Suddenly this error started to appear when one of our programmers is trying to make a web deploy to our Microsoft Server 2008 . We cant find any meaningful information about this error. Also, most topics that we have found are related to Azure.

Does anybody know what this error means?

Update,

For everybody that will tell me to Google the issue:
yes, I goggled the issues. No, I couldn't solve the problem.
I event looked on this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS). The error isn't even posted

Comment: [Google does](https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), you need to eliminate the obvious answers first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I deleted the web server in IIS and created a new one. This is still a weird errorr...